# Image going outside of container

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that I want overlapping the banner but I am having a problem when I re-size the window the image does not move with it. Ive provided a screenshot and my css.

[image: the image]

CSS:

```
.coslogo {
    display: block;
    margin: -150px auto 0;
    top: 150%;
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 590px;
    z-index: 9;
}

.coslogo img {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your position set to absolute because of how you are positioning your overlapping banner. You'll want to add `position:relative;` to the css for .coslogo. I can't be more specific without the html, so include that if this doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `relative` and `absolute` positioning with `z-index` to place the image on one another.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img2 {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img class="img1" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
  <img class="img2" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
</div>
```

Comment: this works but I want the image to be  top: 820px;
  left: 500px
and when I do that its back to square one.